# Importing a global function vs. Defining a global function (Python)

Tags: python, import, global-functions

I found an interesting behavior in Python which I would like to fully understand.

setup.py:

```
good='hello'
def isGood(testGood): return testGood == good
print(isGood('hello'))
print(isGood('bye'))
good='bye'
print(isGood('bye'))
```

Output is:

```
True
False
True
```

main.py:

```
from setup import *
print(good)
print(isGood('hello'))
good='hello'
print(good)
print(isGood('hello'))
```

Output is:

```
True
False
True
bye
False
hello
False
```

In short: Function isGood() is sensitive to the changes of global variable 'good' when the function is used inside setup.py. However, once imported (with from setup import *), the function is no more sensitive to changes of variable 'good'.
There is no difference in the behavior if declaring 'global good' (it is also not expected to make such, in this case).

How is this explained? It is if the function content (non-input variables) are "compiled" after the import.
I'm looking for a source that documents this behavior (to know if it can be trusted).

Comment: Python has module level globals and not process level globals.

Comment: "the function is no more sensitive to changes of variable 'good'." It absolutely is, you just never changed that variable.`good` in `main` is an entirely different variable. This is 100% expected behavior

Comment: See: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html

Answer (score 1):

When you use `from module import *` you will create duplicate instances of them locally.

In your example, `good` in `main.py` is just a copy of `good` in `setup.py`, and changing it in `main.py` does not affect the variable in `setup.py`.

If you want to be able to access it, You can use one of these methods below:

### Method 1

Use a function to set the variable:

#### `setup.py`

```py
def set_good(value):
    global good
    good = value
```

#### `main.py`

```py
from setup import *

set_good('bye')
```

### Method 2

Use a class to keep the variable

```py
class variables:
    good = 'good'

def isGood(testGood): 
    return testGood == variables.good
```

#### `main.py`

```py
from setup import *

variables.good = 'bye'
```

### Method 3

Import module and access the variable

#### `main.py`

```py
import setup

setup.isGood('hello')  # True
setup.good = 'bye'
setup.isGood('bye')    # True
```

Comment: "When you use from module import * you will create duplicate instances of them locally." This says it all, thanks.

Comment: I think it is even more accurate to say that using "from mymodule import *" will duplicate all immutable variables in mymodule, whereas mutable variables are preserved (pointing to the same memory address).

Comment: Well to be more exact even if you import a mutable variable like a list, still you won't be able to change it with `mylist = []`. You can just access its methods and fields like removing or adding to it.

Comment: What you are describing is the normal use of mutable variables.